# location of pip.conf file

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am working on a system that has to work on both Windows and Linux.  Its uses Python's `venv` module for everything related to Python.  I need to create a `pip.conf` file to activate the pickup of my personal `~/.pip/pip.conf` to point it to our internal PyPi server instead of the global one. I also need to be able to hard code the values right into the `venv`'s `pip.conf` for other scenarios.  I can't figure out where the file should be placed.

In short, sometimes I need it to use my personal `pip.conf`, sometimes I need it to use the `venv`'s `pip.conf`, on both Linux and Windows (my machine is Windows).

The folder structure of my `venv` after creation is this:

```
myproject/build/venv/Include
                    /Lib
                    /Scripts
```

Where does the `pip.conf` go? I keep reading in the documentation `%virtual_env%/pip.conf` but when you don't know what the value of virtual_env, its a pretty useless statement.

My guess is `myproject/build/venv/pip.conf`, am I right?

edit**

Well, I was wrong. Putting it in the root of the `venv` folder didn't work. I'm going to keep trying, problem is to redeploy this app after each code change takes an hour.

Comment: What happened when you tried putting the file at `myproject/build/venv/pip.conf`?  Did it work?

Comment: i haven't tried yet.  its an automated process, not a console and changing it is a bitch.  I only want to do it once if i can

Comment: That's an unusual venv setup. The common way to do it is to have one umbrella directory housing all venvs. A popular location for this (e.g. that's how "oh-my-zsh" does it) is `~/.virtualenvs/`. Your "myproject" virtualenv would then be at `~/.virtualenvs/myproject/` and your pip config thus at `~/.virtualenvs/myproject/pip.conf`. Your project itself would be in its own directory elsewhere, e.g. `~/projects/myproject/`. It may additionally (quite optional) have a `.venv` file that explicitly specifies its virtualenv's location.

Answer (score 27):

The easiest way to locate the folder is by running the following command in the cmd.

`pip config -v list`

That will result with the paths that pip is searching in to find the config file. There are different paths for `global`, `user`, `site`. And you can even add one for you specific needs.

Comment: this didnt give the paths for me.
pip config debug worked.
pip version 21.2.4, python 3.9

Answer (score 4):

According to pip user guide https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file it's `pip.ini` under Windows, not `pip.conf`.

It should be at the root of your virtual environnement, right where you tried with `pip.conf`, and takes precedence over your personal `%APPDATA%/pip/pip.ini`.

Comment: I tried every combination in that doc.  None worked.  I finally forked pip and just hard coded the URL.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me to obtain all the config files was

```
pip config debug
```

(It seems to do what `pip config -v list` did before)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the configuration is stored at `C:\Users\<username>\.virtualenvs\<virtual env name>\pip.ini`
Ref: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file