# pip.conf location on a conda environment

Tags: pip, conda

I couldn't find the `pip.conf` file when I was on an active conda environment.
Where is `pip.conf` file located when I'm working on an active conda environment?

Comment: [`pip config -v list`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65424781/7976758) Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22pip.conf%22+location

Answer (score 5):

That file may exist in your machine by order of priority:
[Priority 1] Site level configuration files
1. `{your conda location}/envs/{your environment name }/pip.conf`

[Priority 2] User level configuration files
1. `/home/${USER}/.config/pip/pip.conf`
2. `/home/${USER}/.pip/pip.conf`

[Priority 3] Global level configuration files
1. `/etc/pip.conf`
2. `/etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf`

Based on  `NVIDIA PyIndex.` notes.

Comment: Here are reported the Windows equivalent folders: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/